# homeomorphism between $D^2\setminus\{0\}$ and open cylinder

Tags: general-topology

Let $$X=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:0<x^2+y^2\leq 1\}\subset \mathbb{R}^2$$
and $$Z=S^1\times(0,1]=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2=1, 0<z\leq 1\}\subset \mathbb{R}^3$$

I have to show these are homeomorphic by giving the homeomorphism. I already know that $X$ is given by $(x,y)=(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta)), r\in(0,1]$ and that $Z$ is given by $(x,y,z)=(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta),z), z\in(0,1]$.

I still find it hard to give the homeomorphism. Anybody who can help me?

Comment: I think you've almost done. Why don't $(x,y,z)\mapsto (zx,zy)$...

Comment: @sigmabe Thank you! I found this homeomorphism now: $f(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta),z)=(z\cos(\theta),z\sin(\theta))$ and then the $z$ and $r$ will have the same domain and $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous, thanks!

Comment: @JBIBB While you in effect describe the *same* map as *sigmabe* does, do you see why sigmabe's description (for the one direction) is "better"?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen ehm.. I thought this was the same.. what is the difference?